# Priority of assign statements in i3 configuration

Tags: i3

I want to assign a specific app to a workspace in i3. That app is `ranger` and I want to launch it via `alacritty`

I've already chosen to launch `alacritty` in `ws_term` workspace and I want to launch `ranger` in `ws_fm`.

Running xprop returns two classes for ranger -> "Ranger", "Alacritty"

In my `i3/config` file I have the following directives (in this exact order):

```
assign [class="Alacritty"] $ws_term
...
assign [instance="Ranger"] $ws_fm
```

The problem is that even though I'm explicitly specifying Ranger as last, it always picks the "Alacritty" class and places the app in the wrong workspace. Same issue if I use `title=` or `class=` instead of `instance`.

How can I set the priority in the `assign` statements in case there are multiple matches for an app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is described in the [userguide](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#assign_workspace):

> Assignments are processed by i3 in the order in which they appear in
> the config file. The first one which matches the window wins and later
> assignments are not considered.

The ranger assignment must be before the alacritty assignment.